# IIS: acess denied to Web.Config file

Tags: iis, web.config

I'm trying to set up a new website in a Windows Server 2003. In this server there is already a website, classic ASP, in port 80. I'm configuring this new one (ASP.NET 3.5) in port 82 with, actually, .NET Framework 4.0, as I keep getting an error when trying to install 3.5.

When accesing the website I get an error saying access to web.config file is denied, if I access a test html file it loads ok.

I also tryed adding an impersonate clause in web.config, for the machine admin user, but no success.

Folder and files have correct permissions for IUSR_SERVERNAME, web server extensions are active and have permissions also (the .NET framework ones). User ASP.NET does not exist in this machine (I read somewhere you also need to give access to this user) so I don't know what else to try.

Help please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Verify your .NET app pools are properly configured with the correct account, whether it is the local system account or a domain service account.